# How do I write my multithreading code correctly so that it is faster than a single thread?

Tags: performance, c, multithreading, ffi

I have the following code that I am trying to optimize. I am running it on a Linux machine with 24 cores. I thought I could use multithreading to make it faster, but it's somehow making it way slower than the single thread. I believe it is because of cache misses but I am not sure how to structure this code to avoid them.

```
#include <stdio.h>              
#include <stdlib.h>             

#include "mex.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "pthread.h"

/* NOT sure why multi-threading is worse than single thread */
#define NTHREADS 1

/* An argument list structure */
struct argList{
    double *X;
    double *p;
    int cycles;
    int N1;
    int N2;
};
typedef struct argList aList;


long int bino_rand(double p, double n)
{
  long int    x = 0;             
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    if (((double)rand())/RAND_MAX < p) x++;

  return(x);
}

void *bino_process(void* arglist){
    double* X   = ((aList*)arglist)->X;
    double* p   = ((aList*)arglist)->p;
    int cycles  = ((aList*)arglist)->cycles;
    int N1      = ((aList*)arglist)->N1;
    int N2      = ((aList*)arglist)->N2;
    int i,j;

/* mexPrintf("N1=%d, N2=%d, cycles=%d\n", N1, N2, cycles); */

for(i = N1;i<N2;i++){
    double tmp = X[i];
    double tmp_p = p[i];
    for(j=0;j<cycles;j++){
        tmp = tmp + bino_rand(tmp_p,tmp);
    }
    X[i] = tmp;
}
}


void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
double* n;              /* input scalar */
double* p;
int cycles;
mwSize N;               /* size of matrix */
double *X;              /* output matrix */
int i;

pthread_t threadA[NTHREADS];
int iterA[NTHREADS];
aList arglistA[NTHREADS];

int N1[NTHREADS];
int N2[NTHREADS];


/* get the value of the scalar input  */
n = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
p = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
cycles = (int)mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);

N = mxGetM(prhs[0]);

/* create the output matrix */
plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N,1,mxREAL);

/* get a pointer to the real data in the output matrix */
X = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);

memcpy(X,n,N*sizeof(double));


for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
    N1[i] = i*(N/NTHREADS);
    N2[i] = (i+1)*(N/NTHREADS);
    arglistA[i].X = X;
    arglistA[i].p = p;
    arglistA[i].cycles = cycles;


    arglistA[i].X = (double*)mxCalloc(N2[i]-N1[i],sizeof(double));
    memcpy(arglistA[i].X, &X[N1[i]], (N2[i]-N1[i])*sizeof(double));

    arglistA[i].N2 = N2[i]-N1[i];        
    arglistA[i].N1 = 0;

}

/* Spawn the threads */
for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
    iterA[i] = pthread_create(&threadA[i],NULL,bino_process,(void*)&arglistA[i]);       
}

/* Join back the threads */
for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
    pthread_join(threadA[i],NULL);      
}

/* Copy back the data from the chunks into X */
for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
    memcpy(&X[N1[i]], arglistA[i].X, (N2[i]-N1[i])*sizeof(double));
}

for(i=0;i<NTHREADS;i++){
    mxFree(arglistA[i].X);
}

}
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: For context, you might want to consider also including additional information such as which code / section of code you're timing, the size of the arrays you're processing, and approximate timings for single/multi threaded runs.  As far as the title goes, I think @Jamal was suggesting something more along the lines of 'Multi-threaded function for calculating XXXX'  where XXXX is whatever it is your code is actually doing.  At the moment, your title is still a description of what you want from the review, not what the code does.

Comment: I still cannot quite tell what this code is supposed to do.  You need to provide more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How did you time your program?

I ran a modified version of your program (I didn't have "mex.h" so I rewrote the parts that needed it).  When I ran your program with 1, 2, and 4 threads, I got the following results:

```
1 thread  = 9.38 sec
2 threads = 4.93 sec
4 threads = 2.81 sec
```

So it seems to be working for me.  How did you time your program?  You may have been using a function such as `clock()` that measures cpu time across all cores, instead of measuring wall clock time.  See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962785/c-using-clock-to-measure-time-in-multi-threaded-programs) for more information on that.

Comment: `mex.h` is provided by MATLAB for its native-code interface.

Comment: I recompiled the code on my laptop and it worked as expected - time goes down as threads increase. Previously, I was running the code on a 24 core linux cluster. May be there is something about the way that server is set up. I can check with the system's admin. I am not experienced multithreading and thought I may be doing something bad, which caused the poor performance. 

I use MATLAB's tic-toc for timing. But also, the multithreading is so slow that it is just obvious without precise timing. The results for some input were 95secs without multithreading and 1111secs with 8 threads.

Comment: @200_success Ah thanks, I've never used matlab before.

Answer (score 2):

After some more Google searching, I found that the fundamental problem is the call to the `rand()` function. It is not thread-safe as it says [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand_r), and then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716005/why-is-this-c11-code-containing-rand-slower-with-multiple-threads-than-with) as well.

So, the solution is to use a thread-safe `rand_r()` function instead. This issue seems to be only on a Linux machine. There is no issue on my MacBook.